# Find five prime factors of $3^{140 }- 1$

Tags: number-theory

I tried to simplify $3^{140}$ but I couldn't go past $81^{35}$, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try Wolfram Alpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factors+of+((3+to+the+140)+-1)

Comment: What kind of class lets you factorise a very large integer? If it's not a computer science class, I don't see the point.

Answer (score 30):

$$3^{140}-1=(3^{70}+1)(3^{70}-1)=(3^{70}+1)(3^{35}+1)(3^{35}-1)$$
and from $a-b\mid a^7-b^7$, the number
$ 3^{35}\pm1$ is a multiple of $3^5\pm1$. These are of feasible size and give us $2, 11, 61$ as prime factors. Also, $3^{35}\pm1$ is a multiple of $3^7\pm1$, which are still of manageable size and give us $547$ and $1093$.

Alternatively, note that $3^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for $p\ne 3$, hence looking for small primes with $p-1\mid 140$ is helpful. This way you find $p=2, 5, 11, 29, 71$ very easily.

Comment: Nice 2nd statement. I think that was the intention of the question.

Answer (score 16):

Hint:  you have a difference of squares, a difference of fifth powers, and a difference of seventh powers.

Answer (score 7):

$$a^n - b^n = (a-b) ( a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$$

Using $n = 140$, we get that $3 - 1$ is a factor, which gives $2$ as a factor.

Using $n = 35$, we get that $3^4 - 1$ is a factor, which gives $5$ as a factor.

Using $n = 28$, we get that $3^5 - 1$ is a factor, which gives $11$ as a factor.

Using $n = 20$, we get that $3^7-1$ is a factor, which gives $1093$ as a factor.

Using $n = 14$, we get that $3^{10} -1 $ is a factor, which gives $61$ as a factor.

Comment: Using $n=140$, we get that $3-1$ is a factor, which gives $2$ as a factor ... slightly-more-easily. ;)

Comment: $3^4-1$ is not divisible by $13$. And, indeed, $13$ is not a factor.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

He asks for primes. So any prime $p\neq 3$ for which $p-1$ divides $140$ is such a prime.

This includes $2,5,11,29,71$. The are not the only prime factors, but they are the first five that we can find.

For example, $4^3\equiv 3\pmod {61}$, so $3^{20}=4^{60}\equiv 1\pmod {61}$. So $61$ is another prime factor.

Comment: I think it would help to explicitly mention which results you are using here, and why $p - 1 \mid 140$ matters. If he knew about that result, he would not be asking this question.

Comment: Lots of people who do know the result posted here without this answer, which is, IMHO, clearly the approach intended by the question, given how it comes up with $5$ primes instantly. :) @TMM

Comment: I'm just saying that I think for the OP it may not be obvious why $p - 1 \mid 140$ implies that $p \mid 3^{140} - 1$. A non-elementary-number-theory-way to solve this problem could be to just factor $3^{140} - 1$ as explained by Hagen, so this question may not even be part of a course on elementary number theory. So the OP may not even know anything about stuff like Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score -1):

python 3

```
print()
print("find the prime factors of an integer")
another = "y"
while another == "y":
    print

    a = (3**140-1)
    b = a
    c = 2
    primes = []
    while b > 1:
        if b % c == 0:
            x  = 0
            while b % c == 0:
                b = b / c
                x = x + 1
            print("    ", c, " is a prime factor of ", a, " ",  x, " times")
            primes.append(c)           
        c = c + 1
    print("     the prime factors of     ", a, "   are ", primes)
    print( "     the largest prime factor of ", a, "  is ", max(primes))
    print()
    another = input("another integer?  y or n   ")

print()
print ("program ended")
```

output

```
find the prime factors of an integer
     2  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   171  times
     3  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   1  times
     53  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   1  times
     97  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   1  times
     8867  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   1  times
     15307379  is a prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   1  times
     the prime factors of      6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800    are  [2, 3, 53, 97, 8867, 15307379]
     the largest prime factor of  6265787482177970379256224194341930332206694446810665274859598050800   is  15307379

another integer?  y or n
```

Comment: The most unpythonic code I've ever seen

Comment: Incorrect result. Actual factors calculated using [Wolfram Alpha](www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor(3**140-1)) : `2^4 × 5^2 × 11^2 × 29 × 61 × 71 × 547 × 1093 × 1181 × 16493 × 28596961 × 32839661 × 94373861 × 2664097031 × 374857981681`  (20 prime factors, 15 distinct)

Comment: Your code gives the wrong result because you used floating point division.

Comment: @Harold: BASIC, written in Python. (Nothing wrong with that use of the tool btw)

Comment: It's not too difficult to see, that $3$ is not a divisor. How did this answer get four upvotes?